# .env file didn't copy into docker container on AWS EB

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have the following project structure locally

```
|-- docker-compose.yml
|-- docker-entrypoint.sh
|-- Dockerfile
|-- nginx
|   `-- loc
|       `-- nginx.conf
|-- poetry.lock
|-- pyproject.toml
`-- src
    |-- my_project
    |   |-- asgi.py
    |   |-- __init__.py
    |   |-- settings.py
    |   |-- urls.py
    |   `-- wsgi.py
    |-- __init__.py
    |-- manage.py
    |-- .env
```

In Dockerfile I have the following line
`COPY /src/ /workdir/`

Elastic Beanstalk takes env variable and stores them in `.env` file by the following path `/var/app/current` then when the container has been built, the env file wasn't copied inside. I made a workaround by copying `.env` file `COPY .env /workdir/` but it doesn't look like a good solution. Should I move everything from `/src` folder to one level above?

Comment: In AWS, the EBS abbreviation stands for Elastic Block Store. Elastic Beanstalk == EB.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you do not have the `.env` file in your `.gitignore`, `.ebignore`, or your `.dockerignore`, otherwise it will not get copied.

Here is a link to the Elastic Beanstalk documentation regarding how the `.env` file is handled with regards to Docker deployments:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_docker.container.console.html#docker-env-cfg.env-variables